# Appium Inspector for Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, appium

I'm unable to record a test for a web application for Mobile Safari within Appium Inspector. I have started server and opened the Appium Inspector. It shows a web page when I click `Record` button but I'm not able to select an element within the web page. I've attached the screenshots:

`Appium Inspector`

[image: Appium Inspector]

`iOS Settings`

[image: iOS Settings]

Answer (score 0):

i think thats not possible at the moment, because appium has no access to the web elements.
Just open the website with your favorite browser and install a mobile plugin (e.g. ripple). This way you can browse the mobile version sourcecode and test you xpath queries etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web inspector instead to identify web elements on real device or simulator.